# ECONNREFUSED - node.js, passport.js, create-react-app, custom middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

y'all, I'm trying to create a signup and login local-Strategy with passport and have been seeing a PROXY ERROR:. I thought I was returning all possible endings for the functions but maybe I'm missing something?  I'm new to development and am going crazy haha...  Any help is much appreciated, also let me know if I missed adding pertinent code. (I did not add the return block from the react component, I assumed it unnecessary).  I am importing my strategies through a strategy index.js (also did not include).

SignupStratagy.js / local strategy

```
const Strategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("../models/User");
// for password encryption;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;

const SignupStrategy = new Strategy({ passReqToCallback: true }, function (
  req,
  username,
  password,
  done
) {
  // console.log(username, password);
  const encryptedPass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);
  // console.log("encryptedPassword", encryptedPass);
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const street = req.body.street;
  const city = req.body.city;
  const state = req.body.state;
  const zip = req.body.zip;
  const isAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;


  User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
    // console.log("SignupStrategy.js / req:", req.body);
    if (err) {
      return done(err, user);
    }

    if (user) {
      return done("User Name is already taken:", user);
    }
  })
    // .lean()
    // .exec();
  // console.log("SignupStrategy.js / encrypted password:", encryptedPass);
  let newUser = {
    username,
    password: encryptedPass,
    phone,
    email,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    isAdmin,
  };

  User.create(newUser, (error, newUser) => {
    if (error) {
      return done(error, null);
    }
    // delete the user password before it is sent back to the front-end;
    newUser.password = undefined;

    delete newUser.password;

    return done(null, newUser);
  });
});

module.exports = SignupStrategy;
```

apiRoute.js / route for signup

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const db = require("../models");
const passport = require("../config");
// const isAuthenticated = require("../config/middleware/isAuthenticated");

// USER SIGN-UP ROUTE
router.post("/api/signup", function (req, res, next) {
  // console.log(req.body);
  passport.authenticate("local-signup", (error, user) => {
    // console.log("apiRoutes.js / error:", error, "apiRoutes.js / user:", user)
    if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: error,
      });
    else {
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Signup / react component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import chip from "../../images/chipper/chipperOne.png";
import "./style.css";

function Signup() {
  const [signupState, setSignupState] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    street: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    zip: "",
    key: "",
    redirect: false,
    adminRedirect: false,
    isAdmin: false,
  });

  const onChange = (e) => {
    // console.log("working")
    // console.log(typeof e.target.type)
    if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
      if (signupState.isAdmin === false) {
        setSignupState({
          ...signupState,
          isAdmin: true,
        })
      } else {
        setSignupState({
          ...signupState,
          isAdmin: false,
        });
      }
    } else {
      setSignupState({
        ...signupState,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (signupState.isAdmin === true) {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/admin-sign-up", {
        key: signupState.key,
      });
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 500) {
        console.log(response);
        return;
      }
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.status);
        setSignupState({
          ...signupState,
          adminRedirect: true,
        });
      }
    }

    // console.log(`onSubmit ${signupState}`);

    axios.post("/api/signup", {
      username: signupState.username,
      password: signupState.password,
      phone: signupState.phone,
      email: signupState.email,
      street: signupState.street,
      city: signupState.city,
      state: signupState.state,
      zip: signupState.zip,
      isAdmin: signupState.isAdmin,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data) {
          console.log(`Sign-in Successful`);
          setSignupState({
            ...signupState,
            redirect: true,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err) console.log(`Sign-Up server error ${err}`);
      });
  };
```

ERROR:
 Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/signup from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Comment: Did you go to that nodejs.org link and read what it had to say about ECONNREFUSED?

Comment: Yes,
ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host.

dug deeper but primarily found to return.
I am returning all possible ends to the function.

Comment: I know what it says. You might be surprised how many questions we get where people don't read the error messages... I'm not sure what "returning all possible ends" means, but I'll let someone with more expertise in passport.js answer as I don't know that framework.